# 1998 toyota corolla automatic cranks but no start

Tags: toyota, starting, corolla

I have a 1998 Toyota corolla automatic transmission that have a difficulty in starting when the car has parked for a period of over 4 hours or when kinda cold, the car starter motor cranks well. After several attempts of cranking the car eventully picks up starting at a lower pace and rising after some few minutes.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: We need the engine size and trim model to properly give you advice.

Comment: engine 1.6 , model is 110

Comment: Does it have a tach?  If so, what's your idle cold and hot in park?  Does giving it a bit of gas help it start?

Comment: What if you hold down the throttle pedal (clear flood mode) when cranking?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you may have a leaking injector. If so, it would be flooding the engine after a period of time, causing the hard start and the slow resumption of running well when it does start.

The easiest way to check my theory is to put a fuel pressure gauge on the fuel rail over the same period of time. Check the pressure after attached, then again in the several hours after when you'd normally see the issue. If it has dropped significantly or all the way to zero, there's a problem in this arena. To further diagnose, you'd then pull up the fuel rail with the injectors attached. Turn the ignition to on (do not start), and check to see if any of the injectors are leaking. You'd want to do this into some sort of container so as to not cause a fuel spill and potential fire hazard.

If it does turn out to be a fuel injector, there are some great videos on YouTube which can show you how to clean them, or take them to a shop and have them do it (at a much greater expense).

Obviously, if the fuel pressure stays up to where it started (as it should), this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a 2001 corolla with similar symptoms. It turned out being a evap issue. 
A real pain in the butt to diagnose. The thing you have to watch with corolla is when you fuel it. Make sure you stop at the first click. Accidentally  overfilling can mess up the charcoal canister can make your life living hell. 
A stuck purge valve can cause flooding issues when hot.

I solved my problem by trading it and buying a 2012 Honda....I didn't have the patience for a extensive and expensive repair.